# Cannot understand why cosine similarity is calculated as $\cos(u,v) = 1 - \frac{u\cdot v}{\|u\|_2 \cdot \|v\|_2}$

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am reading [this article (PDF via arXiv.org)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.04047.pdf).

At page 3 of the PDF, right column, under section 3.2 "Quantifying Bias Removal", there is a formula to calculate the cosine distance between two vectors:

$$\cos(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}) = 1 - \dfrac{\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v}}{\|u\|_2 \cdot \|v\|_2} \tag1$$

But I thought that in an Euclidean space:

$$\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \|u\|_2 \cdot \|v\|_2 \cdot \cos(\theta) \tag2$$

So the right hand side of $(1)$ would be $ 1-\cos(\theta) $ and not $\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: It seems that the paper $defines$ "cosine difference" (not "cosine") this way for their own purposes.

Comment: Wikipedia's ["cosine similarity" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) notes that *"The term cosine distance is often used for the complement [of cosine similarity] in positive space, that is: $D_C(A,B)=1−S_C(A,B)$, where $D_C$ is the cosine distance and $S_C$ is the cosine similarity [defined by $\frac{A\cdot B}{\|A\|\|B\|}$] ."*

Comment: You want the distance to be zero when the vectors are parallel, one when they are orthogonal. That's what $1-\cos\theta$ does for you.

Comment: You've had an answer, raffaem, and several comments. Any response to these?

Comment: It's not optimal behavior, raffaem, to ask people for help, and then fail to engage when help is provided.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know, but I thought that on SE the way to say "thanks" was to upvote the answer and comments. I did that

Comment: Upvoting is good, raffaem, and I'm glad you did that. But for answers, if an answer resolves your question, you also have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it. The upvote could come from anyone; the acceptance can only come from the person posting the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson anyway I understand how "cosine distance" is not cosine and your comment on what the "1-" does makes a lot of sense. Thank you all very much for your help

Comment: @GerryMyerson ok, I accepted the only answer I have received and upvoted the most helpful comments (I think if you had put what the "1-" does in an answer that would have been a good answer to accept too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that "cosine distance" is actually **different** from "cosine"(which is defined in analytical geometry textbooks). It is just a new concept lead into the context by the author himself for further descriptions.